# Prove a case that is a little bit different from Fermat Numbers

Tags: proof-writing, fermat-numbers

Prove that for every integer $n\geq1$ the number $2^{2^n}$ has at least n distinct divisors.

I have no idea on how to do this. I cannot comprehend what the Wikipedia explanation says.

Comment: It has divisors $2^k$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,2^n$.  That's $2^n+1$ divisors, which is at least $n$.

Comment: Do you know the divisor function $d(n)$?

Comment: Do you mean $2^{2^n}$ or $2^{2^n}-1$?  In the latter case we can even extract distinct *prime* divisors.  In the former case it is trivial to extract far more divisors than is asked for.